# Android Bluetooth connecting to Device socket.connect() wont connect

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, bluetooth

> FIXED!!!

Didnt work because of the UUID
since api15 you can use a get function to get the uuid

```
UID uuid = bluetoothDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid(); 
BluetoothSocket socket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
```

> FIXED!!!

I am trying to connect to a devie to write data onto it.
I can search for devices and if i click the connect thread gets started, but the "run()" function isnt called. The programm is stucked at

Right now i am trying to connect to a bluetooth headset. 
I dont know if i am pairing the two devices? if i use the normal bluetooth of the phone, i am pairing the two devices with a code like 1 2 3 4  but in my program you dont have to enter a code. Can you help me pls?

> mmSocket.connect();

So my connectedthread() never runs!

here is my full code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

```
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
ListView newDevicesListView;
   // Return Intent extra
public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";
private ConnectingDevices mConnectingDevices = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    newDevicesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
    newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

    mConnectingDevices = new ConnectingDevices();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClickbtnEtage1(View view)
{
mConnectingDevices.write(new byte[2]);
}


public void onClickbtnActivateBluetooth(View view)
{

      if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) 
      {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth ist nicht verfügbar!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
      }
      else if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
      {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
      }
      Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth wurde aktiviert!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      findViewById(R.id.btnSearchDevices).setEnabled(true);


}

public void onClickbtnSearchDevices(View view)
{
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Geräte werden gesucht!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices 
}

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
 private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) 
                {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }


            }
        }
    };

    // The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
            // Set result and finish this Activity
        //    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
          // finish();



                address = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
                BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                // Attempt to connect to the device
                mConnectingDevices.connect(device);


        }

    };}
```

and my connectingdevices class

```
        public class ConnectingDevices {

boolean bconnectedthread = false;
boolean bconnectthread = false;
boolean bconnectedthreadstart = false;
boolean bconnectthreadstart = false;
boolean brun=false;
boolean bconnectedsynchronized=false;
//00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    //private final Handler mHandler;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;

    public void write(byte[] out) {
        boolean a=bconnectedthread;
        boolean b=bconnectthread;
        boolean c=bconnectedthreadstart;
        boolean d=bconnectthreadstart;
        boolean e=brun;
        boolean f=bconnectedsynchronized;

        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {

            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);

    }

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        bconnectthread = true;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       brun=true;
        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        //bconnectedthreadstart = true;

       connected(mmSocket);

    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}


private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        bconnectedthread=true;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
               // mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                  //      .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}


public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) 

{  
    bconnectthreadstart=true;
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();

}


public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket) {

    bconnectedsynchronized=true;
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();


}}



logcat
    05-21 17:49:29.902: W/dalvikvm(25720): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417da498)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3676)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4171)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17070)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4797)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:804)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:571)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3671)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    ... 11 more
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at com.example.elevator.ConnectingDevices.write(ConnectingDevices.java:40)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    at com.example.elevator.MainActivity.onClickbtnEtage1(MainActivity.java:63)
    05-21 17:49:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(25720):    ... 14 more
    05-21 17:49:49.062: I/System.out(27064): Debugger has connected
    05-21 17:49:49.062: I/System.out(27064): waiting for debugger to settle...
    05-21 17:49:49.262: I/System.out(27064): waiting for debugger to settle...
    05-21 17:49:49.472: I/System.out(27064): waiting for debugger to settle...
    05-21 17:49:49.663: I/System.out(27064): waiting for debugger to settle...
    05-21 17:49:49.863: I/System.out(27064): waiting for debugger to settle...
    05-21 17:49:50.063: I/System.out(27064): waiting for debugger to settle...
    05-21 17:49:50.263: I/System.out(27064): waiting for debugger to settle...
    05-21 17:49:50.474: I/System.out(27064): debugger has settled (1455)
    05-21 17:49:50.684: W/ResourceType(27064): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
    05-21 17:49:50.684: W/PackageManager(27064): Failure retrieving resources forcom.example.elevator: Resource ID #0x0
    05-21 17:49:50.944: D/IconCustomizer(27064): Generate customized icon for com.example.elevator.png
    05-21 17:49:50.984: W/IconCustomizer(27064): can't load transform_config.xml
    05-21 17:49:51.164: I/themeservice(27064): add pending job /data/data/com.example.elevator/cache/com.example.elevator.png
    05-21 17:49:51.174: I/themeservice(27064): binding service
    05-21 17:49:51.344: I/themeservice(27064): service connected
    05-21 17:49:51.344: I/themeservice(27064): saving icon for /data/data/com.example.elevator/cache/com.example.elevator.png
    05-21 17:49:51.415: I/Adreno200-EGL(27064): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:294>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3068996)
    05-21 17:49:51.415: I/Adreno200-EGL(27064): Build Date: 03/07/13 Thu
    05-21 17:49:51.415: I/Adreno200-EGL(27064): Local Branch: au37
    05-21 17:49:51.415: I/Adreno200-EGL(27064): Remote Branch: 
    05-21 17:49:51.415: I/Adreno200-EGL(27064): Local Patches: 
    05-21 17:49:51.415: I/Adreno200-EGL(27064): Reconstruct Branch: 
    05-21 17:49:52.346: I/themeservice(27064): unbinding service
    05-21 17:50:36.903: I/ConnectingDevices(27064): connectthread function started
    05-21 17:50:36.903: I/ConnectingDevices(27064): connectthread is working
    05-21 17:50:36.913: I/ConnectingDevices(27064): connectthread is running
    05-21 17:50:36.953: E/ConnectingDevices(27064): mmSocket unable to connect
    05-21 17:50:36.953: E/ConnectingDevices(27064): java.io.IOException: Unable to start Service Discovery
    05-21 17:50:36.953: E/ConnectingDevices(27064):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:455)
    05-21 17:50:36.953: E/ConnectingDevices(27064):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:230)
    05-21 17:50:36.953: E/ConnectingDevices(27064):     at com.example.elevator.ConnectingDevices$ConnectThread.run(ConnectingDevices.java:77)
```

Comment: What error it gives? And where is mConnectingDevices instantiate?

Comment: mConnectingDevices.connect(device);  << this line gives me an error

Comment: i can see that i got a mac-address for the "device" arguement, but he wont connect. The programm stopps. If I try to continue the programm, it says "source not found".  "mConnectingDevices" is the object to my class "Connecting Devices" and in this class, there is the "connect" function

Comment: I am not initializing it...damn:)

Comment: What the status? It's working?

Comment: No actually its not. Now it my program runs the connect thread, but it wont run the "connectedThread" to mange everything. It seems like the function "mmSocket.Connect()" blocks everything and cant get smartphone connect to the device. I am trying to connect to a bluetooth headphone. Is this not possible? can you help me? :/

Comment: Could it be that my problem is with the pairing of the devices?

Comment: In another threat i read that it could be because of the UUID

Comment: Can be a lot of things, you should focus on what error its showing to you. Please post the log where it is the error.

Comment: like i said: it throws an exception at the point where mmSocket calls connect()
05-21 17:50:36.953: E/ConnectingDevices(27064): mmSocket unable to connect

Comment: OK found the answester on another stackoverflow thread

Comment: UUID uuid = bluetoothDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid();
BluetoothSocket socket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);


since api15 you can get the uuid from the device and with this uuid its working:)

Comment: Nice, please post the answer here in case someone else have the same problem :)